# AngularJS: Ngtable reload to old data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngtable

So I'm using NGTable to display data on my page, the data are stored in an array and passed through the dataset param but when I programmatically change the value of a data in the array the changes are displayed correctly in the table **BUT** when I go to the second page for and go to the first page again the table display the old data.

Here is a JSFiddle that illustrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/vqxscmsu/

```
    angular.module("uCloud", ["ngTable"])
  .controller("myController", myController);

myController.$inject = ["NgTableParams", "$scope"];

function myController(NgTableParams, $scope) {

        $scope.fsck = [{
      name: "teste1",
      description: "testando1"
    }, {
      name: "teste2",
      description: "testando2"
    }, {
      name: "teste3",
      description: "testando3"
    }, {
      name: "teste4",
      description: "testando4"
    }, {
      name: "teste2",
      description: "testando2"
    }, {
      name: "teste3",
      description: "testando3"
    }, {
      name: "teste4",
      description: "testando4"
    }, {
      name: "teste2",
      description: "testando2"
    }, {
      name: "teste3",
      description: "testando3"
    }, {
      name: "teste4",
      description: "testando4"
    }, {
      name: "teste2",
      description: "testando2"
    }, {
      name: "teste3",
      description: "testando3"
    }, {
      name: "teste4",
      description: "testando4"
    }, {
      name: "teste2",
      description: "testando2"
    }, {
      name: "teste3",
      description: "testando3"
    }, {
      name: "teste4",
      description: "testando4"
    }]


        this.tableParams = {
    TodoGeneral: null
  };
  this.tableParams['TodoGeneral'] = new NgTableParams({}, {
    dataset: $scope.fsck,
  });

 $scope.test = function() {
    $scope.fsck[0].name = "mais non";
 }
}
```

Comment: Because you stored data in `$scope`, `$scope` will reinit with your init data in your controller. If you want to change, you can store to localStorage, or Cookie, Or $rootScope.

Comment: @TanDuong I tried to replace with $rootScope but the problem is still there

Comment: Maybe you can try with sessionStorage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `getData` instead of `dataset` in your `NgTableParams` instantiation.
then you can update your table via `tableName.reload()` which goes and calls `getData` method.

The only thing that differs here is the behavior in pagination which you may want to reread in documentations.

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vqxscmsu/17/

```
var demo = this;
// ...
demo.tableParams['TodoGeneral'] = new NgTableParams({}, {
    getData: function(){
       return $scope.fsck;
     }
});

$scope.test = function() {
    $scope.fsck[0].name = "mais non";
    demo.tableParams.TodoGeneral.reload();
}
```

Comment: I had to add some stuff in the getData() function to get sorting, filters, pagination to work. But now the problem is fixed with this solution, thanks you !

Comment: Yeah I recalled it but didn't remember exactly what to do!